# Compilation Error C++

Tags: c++, кодировка

В visual studio ошибок нет, но отправляя в тестовую систему выдает Compilation Error, скорее всего он ругается на SetConsoleCP и SetConsoleOutputCP, можно ли эти две строки заменить на что-то другое, чтобы читались русские символы?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main() {
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // нужно заменить эти две строки на что-то подобное
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    std::string str;
    getline(std::cin, str);

    std::string vowels = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";

    bool event = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (vowels.find(str[i]) == vowels.npos && isspace(str[i]) == false) {
            event = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if (event) std::cout << "YES";
    else std::cout << "NO";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Какая тестовая система?

Comment: Нужно знать, в какой кодировке тестовая система отдает кириллицу.

Comment: Если  `#include <windows.h>` уже порождает ошибку компиляции, то тестовая система на linux. Там используется кодировка UTF8 почти всюду, включая кодировку текста исходных файлов..